# New mail in inbox not showing in Outlook 2010 client

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-2010, exchange-migration

Hello this week i've migrated an old Mdeamon mailserver to Exchange 2013 this is done by importing all the mailboxes using a pst file. The whole migration went fine. Yet there's one Mailbox where in the inbox no new emails are shown on Outlook 2010 on the client's computer (only the old mails from before the migration). The weird thing is that the numbers of unread mails are correctly shown and Properties -> Synchronization is showing the correct amount of emails yet the emails after the migration date are not shown. Checking email using OWA or Activesync shows that all emails are there and can be used. So it seems only related to Outlook 2010 and Exchange 2013.

Has anyone encountered this problem ? And is there a way to reset the inbox in exchange ?

Comment: Try resetting the view in Outlook. - http://www.outlook-tips.net/beginner-user/reset-the-view-in-outlook

Comment: Did you use the Outlook Cache mode? If yes please reset the outlook profile fully and re-download everything.

Comment: @joeqwerty That did the trick for me thanks. It was only showing mails marked for removal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting the view in Outlook.

http://www.outlook-tips.net/beginner-user/reset-the-view-in-outlook